# backend/frontend separation in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I come from a Codeigniter background. At the moment I am building a CMS  in Laravel.

What I would like to know is how can I separate the backend and frontend in Laravel?

In Codeigniter i use to make two controller Admin_Controller and Front_Controller.

```
Article extends Admin_Controller
Article extends Front_Controller
```

and the file structure looked like this

```
controller
--admin
---user
---blog
---news
--user 
--blog
--news
```

for admin controller  I make separate folder and front end controller remain in root of controller folder.

Should I use the same logic in Laravel or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: With Laravel the 'how do I architect'-type questions are very much up to you. I think the system you proposed, that you already know and use, is perfectly fine.

Comment: Your question isn't really about separating front and back ends, but about how to organize your files. Choose whatever file structure is easiest to work with.  Laravel doesn't care which files are in which folders so long as they can be properly autoloaded.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you want to create thinks like Taylor Otwell and 'the core' is trying to teach people do things in Laravel, this is a good start:

Your files could be organized as

```
├── app
│   ├── ZIP
│   │   ├── Controllers
│   │   │   ├── Admin
│   │   │   │   ├── Base.php <--- your base controller
│   │   │   │   ├── User.php
│   │   │   │   ├── Blog.php
│   │   │   │   ├── News.php
│   │   │   ├── Front
│   │   │   │   ├── Base.php <--- your base controller
│   │   │   │   ├── User.php
│   │   │   │   ├── Blog.php
│   │   │   │   ├── News.php
```

Configure a PSR-0 or PSR-4 (better) to autoload your classes:

```
"psr-0": {
    "ZIP": "app/"
},
```

Create namespaces to all tour classes, according to your source tree:

```
<?php namespace ZIP\Controllers\Admin

class User extends Base {

}


<?php namespace ZIP\Controllers\Front

class Blog extends Base {

}
```

And create your base controllers

```
<?php namespace ZIP\Controllers\Admin

use Controller;

class Base extends Controller {

}
```

Comment: I don't understand why someone downvoted on this. This is perfectly valid answer to this question. App structure here is superb here!

Comment: Looks like we have some haters around... :)

Comment: yup i didnt expect  that even this answer an get downvote ,one up from me

Comment: Does the name ZIP have any special meaning here?

Comment: No , my username was ZIP on stackoverflow that time.

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro What about separate users, users cookies and all that stuff?

Comment: I see one problem that would make me downvote, the main reason to have separation, how do you run the backend on one server and the frontend on another... Separately (so you have useful separation)?

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly do it the two controllers way or if you like even more separation (and a more 'laravel' way), write your front end and backend as separate packages (previously called bundles in Laravel 3).

They basically behave like standalone applications within your main app. They can have their own routes, models, controllers etc. You can also write 'core code' at the main application level which can be shared across the packages.

If you are moving to Laravel as you want to learn a new framework, then you should definitely try and get a handle on packages - very powerful.

If you are being 'made' to move to Laravel, or have some time pressure, just do it as you have normally done. Laravel is flexible and will be fine either way you do it.

For more info, see the docs.

Laravel current version (4 at time of writing) - http://laravel.com/docs/packages

Laravel 3 - http://three.laravel.com/docs/bundles

Comment: @gaz-edge : Is there any separation like frontend and backend like Yii advanced template? I mean any link to already implemented repository on githhub or elsewhere?